# Volley Post Method MultiParams Error

Tags: java, android, post, android-volley

I was trying Post method with using Volley and I got: `com.android.google.volley server error.`
I tested my api in postman and it works.
Here is my code:

```
        StringRequest request=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("Response", response);

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.e("Error :",error.getMessage());
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();


                    params.put("name", film.toString());
                    params.put("email", spin.toString());
                    params.put("password", spin_iki.toString());
                    params.put("address", spin_uc.toString());
                    params.put("brand", name.toString());

                    return params;

                }
            };

            RequestQueue queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(film.this);
            queue.add(request);
        }
    });
```

Normally I use my api like http://myurl/api/values/Post?film=...&email=...
How can I fix this? Thank you.This my API's Post method code

```
  [HttpPost]
    public int Post_film(string name, string email, string password, string address, string brand)
    {
        using (var context = new Entities())
        {


            db_table nesne = new db_table();
            nesne.name =name;
            nesne.email = email;
            nesne.password = password;
            nesne.address = address;
            nesne.brand = brand;
            context.db_table.Add(nesne);


            int i = context.SaveChanges();
            return i;

        }
    }
```

this my Postman SS
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4odm2.png)

Comment: If your server is expecting a POST request, why would you send the parameters like "?film=something&email=something" ? You send the parameters via URL when making GET requests, not POST.

Comment: Thank you for answer,as you said my server expect Post request but i tested in postman with params and i have to use ? symbol,if you want i can put postman ss and i put my api post method code

Comment: Yes, that would help to solve the problem, since your Volley code is OK.

Comment: okey now you can see Postman SS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, you're sending a POST request but still adding parameters via URL. If your server is taking these parameters from the URL, then your Volley request will never work because overriding getParams() only works for parameters inside the request body, not parameters attached to the URL. You should either change the way your server is taking the parameters or, in your Android code, generate a string URL with all the parameters attached to it like "http:://myUrl.com/?email=something&name=something". To me, the most logical option is to change your server side code, because it doesn't make too much sense to expect a POST request with parameters in the URL. Parameters in POST requests should be inside the request body,

Comment: you are right,i change my api code and added [FromBody] and published but stil doesn't work.i still getting same error com.android.google.volley ServerError :( and [FromBody] is works,tested

Comment: Ok,i solved problem but [FromBody] doesnt work so i changed [FromUri] instead of [FromBody].Now codes are working,thank you for your helps